# Rstudio plot window shows up hidden behind taskbar even though taskbar is unlocked

Tags: windows, plot, rstudio

My taskbar is unlocked as you can see below, but for some reason the bottom of the graph in the RStudio plot window is cut off by the taskbar and lies behind it in the order of the OS. I have never had this problem before, though sometimes my taskbar is locked even when I ask it to be unlocked.

[image]

I followed the procedure here (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-cant-unlock-my-windows-10-taskbar/a3f42d34-884e-4897-ae16-dc4f8cc9af91) to restart explorer and it still remains locked in front of the RStudio plot.